# Array overlaps an array in Postgres

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typescript, knex.js

I'm making a search by tags function, in a table like this

```sql
    CREATE TABLE permission (
      id serial primary key,
      tags varchar(255)[],
    );
```

Then I add a row that has the tags "artist" and "default".

I'd like to query it by tags (using the [knex query builder](https://knexjs.org/)), so if I do this:

```
  async getByTags(tags: string[]): Promise<PermissionTable[]> {
    return this.db<PermissionTable>('permission')
      .select('*')
      .whereRaw("tags @> '{??}'", [tags])
  }
```

That produces the following statements depending on how many tags you passed.

This works

```sql
    select * from "permission" where tags @> '{"artist"}';
```

This doesn't (returns an empty array, when it should the row I'm looking for)

```sql
    select * from "permission" where tags @> '{"artist", "event"}';
```

Why does the one with multiple tags not work?

Comment: Using ?? replacement there has SQL injection hole. Those are meant only for passing identifier names with correct quotes to the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`@>` is the "contains" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) so `a1 @> a2` is true when `a1` contains all the elements in `a2`. For example:

```
array['artist', 'default'] @> array['artist']            -- True
array['artist', 'default'] @> array['default', 'artist'] -- True
array['artist', 'default'] @> array['artist', 'event']   -- False
```

So `@>` is checks if the right operand is a set-wise subset of the left operand.

I think you're looking for the "overlaps" operator:

> `&&`
>   overlap (have elements in common)
>   `ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1] -- True`

This operator checks if the set-wise intersection of the left and right operands is non-empty.

Something like:

```
.whereRaw("tags && '{??}'", [tags])
```

should server you better.